# how to expire a key of a map in REDIS?

Tags: redis

I use redis to store the users information.

i set many use's info under the key "user",like this:

```
"hset user userid1234 {...}".
```

how to make the key "userid1234" in the user expires in some seconds later?

there is some commands like "expire" which can only set the timeout of user
but i dont want all in it expires.

is there some solutions?

Comment: From what I can tell, it's not possible. If this feature is essential for you, you might have to reconsider the way that you store information. For example. instead of a "hset user userid1234 {...}" you could have "set user:1234 {...}" and set a ttl.

Comment: it's ok,but not so convenient to use "user:1234 {..}".i must use key user* to get the online users.there is not commands like hlen which is O(1). Is my data model is strange?  I think commands like "hexpire amap afiled seconds" is usefull.

Comment: You could try to index your elements in another zset (with time as score) and then periodically check it and manually remove "expired" elements in a lua script for instance.

Comment: 2024-03-31: Redis started implementing hash field expiration, and it's planned for an upcoming release. https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/13172

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `TTL` lives on the key, not on the member. And this won't change.

On how to deal with this, read Josiah Carlson's suggestions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redis-db/44NWMLanGdI). I can also recommend reading his book.

Cheers, TW