# How are lists treated in terms of eviction in redis?

Tags: redis, evict

The problem I'm facing is that i want to make sure lists are evicted in it's entirety. I.e. make sure that entries in the list is not separate evicted. We're looking to use the LRU eviction algorithm.

I realize a list is known by it's key, so that most likely what will happen when a list is evicted is that it will evict the entire list by it's key. Is there any documentation or proof otherwise that i can read to make sure this is the case, or is this so self-explanatory that it's not necessary to point out?

Comment: It's the entire key, always. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954851/how-to-expire-a-key-of-a-map-in-redis/22957376#22957376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tw Bert says, it behaves the same way as hashes and sets, always on the key. Basically answered in: [how to expire a key of a map in REDIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954851/how-to-expire-a-key-of-a-map-in-redis/22957376#22957376)